# Прокладка для отправки отзывов на Яндекс Карты

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Возможно ли реализовать прокладку для написания отзывов на Яндекс Карты? Т.е. пользователь сначала заходит на прокладку, авторизовывается, пишет отзыв, отправляет на Карты.

Answer (score 1):

В текущей версии API Яндекс.Карт не предусмотрена работа с отзывами. Их можно оставить только со страницы организации на самих картах, куда можно перейти по клику с [карточки](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/search_control_ppo) найденной - "Об организации".

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!